# How do you say ‘axiomatize’ in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

How do you say ‘axiomatize’ in Esperanto? - as in ‘Peano axiomatized Arithmetic.’
I want to say ‘aksiomatizi’, but it seems that the suffix ‘atizi’ (or ‘tizi’) is recognized in Esperanto.

Answer (score 5):

The right expression for this in Esperanto is "aksiomigi". It is already used by specialists in the field, for example in the article "Evoluo de matematiko kaj moderna matematika fiziko" by Shigeaki Nagamachi, published in the proceedings of IKU2005: http://www.uea.org/pdf/IKU2005.pdf. This expression is well-formed according to the word formation rules of Esperanto. It can be used equally in scientific texts and in non-specialist texts.

Comment: But he also uses ‘kalkulo’ for ‘calculus’ instead of the standard (?) word ‘analitiko’.

Comment: @MikeJones Wouldn't *analitiko* be analysis rather than calculus?

Comment: @Joffysloffy: That's what I would have thought, but it's apparently a false friend: http://vortaro.net/#analitiko

Comment: @MikeJones That is odd, since *furiera analitiko* seems to be Fourier analysis. What would actual analysis be then?

Comment: @Joffysloffy: I'm not sure, but maybe Esperanto uses the same word for both. Remember that languages divide up the semantic space differently. One language may conflate meanings that another does not. For example, English conflates the two meanings of 'welcome', but Esperanto does not.

Comment: @MikeJones That could be. But then they're not false friends though, are they?

Comment: @Joffysloffy: I guess you're right; I was using 'false friend' in the wide sense of 'something to be careful of'. I guess my sense of 'false friend' is a false friend!

Comment: La angla "calculus" historie estas mallongigo de "infinitesimal calculus". Ĝia Esperantigo do estas "senfinecona kalkulo" aŭ "infinitezima kalkulo" ("senfinecono" estas sinonimo de "infinitezimo", kiu estas formita laŭ Esperanta vortfarado anstataŭ esti rekte transprenita el la latina). "Analitiko" (angle "analysis") estas branĉo de la matematiko, kiu formiĝis per rigora studo de tiuj funkcioj, kiujn la senfinecona kalkulo studas en malpli rigora maniero.

Comment: Shigeaki Nagamachi en sia artikolo uzas "infinitezima kalkulo", kiu estas tute bona esprimo. Li mencias, ke ĝiaj du partoj nomiĝas "diferenciala kalkulo" kaj "integra kalkulo", ankaŭ tute ĝuste. La artikolo ŝajnas tute fidinda rilate la matematikan terminaron, kiun ĝi uzas.

Comment: @MikeJones Haha, I see, indeed!  

@ MarcosCramer Aha, bone, dankon pro via klarigo!

Comment: old joke: Q: What is Analysis? A: Analysis is Calculus done correctly.

Answer (score 3):

So, if I understand correctly, *axiomatise* is to provide a theory with axioms.
There are a few ways to express this in Esperanto without the use of borrowing yet another new root, I list them from most clear/longest to least clear (but clear in context)/shortest:

- *provizi/havigi per aksiomoj*
- *aksiomozigi* (problem: unofficial *-oz-*)
- *aksiomigi*
- *aksiomumi*

In a scientific text I'd propably go with *aksiomigi*, in a non-specialist text I'd prefer the periphrasis.